# making an html file accessible outside of ubuntu using apache2

Tags: html, apache, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu and am trying to create a html file that I can access outside of Ubuntu using apache2. I am using ubuntu (12.04) within a vmware player. I have installed apache2 and created a html document using text editor, which I can open it using a browser within ubunutu, but when I try to open in my regular browser - windows 8, it cannot find the file. I know that it is finding apache2, cause when I type the ip address in the windows browser it says It works! so the problem is I do not know how to save/convert the html file i have created in the text editor so that i can open it in my windows browser. Can someone please instruct me on how to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in /var/www/

save it as index.html

Comment: If you dont name the file "index" apache will show you a listing of all the files in "/var/www"

Answer (score 0):

If you dont name the file "index" apache will show you a listing of all the files in "/var/www".
You will need to get use to using a "command line", this is how the things your getting into are done.

Example: 
sudo mv index.html /var/www 
This command will move index.html to /var/www

Here are some vids that will point you in the right direction


Introduction to Servers:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=CDxaRfwzFrs


Basic Linux Tasks:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=OnSUX2otYos